Проверка на ботов
Я планирую создать бота для Telegram, который будет проверять пользователей на предмет того, являются ли они ботами. Однако, я не совсем уверен, как лучше всего осуществить такую проверку. Единственная идея, которая приходит мне в голову, — это анализировать время вступления пользователей в мой канал. Если многие из них присоединились примерно в одно и то же время, вероятность того, что это боты, высока. Может быть, кто-то знает другие способы проведения такой проверки?

Если бы такое было возможно, такие боты уже давно существовали бы. Ну а критерий «многие из них присоединились примерно в одно и то же время» разумеется чушь

Так вроде полно таких ботов - капча же
